# Laravel/Homestead: No connection could be made using php artisan schema:dump

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, connection, homestead

I'm using Laravel 8/Homestead.
After calling `php artisan schema:dump` from my host's prompt I get an error saying that no connection to database could be made:

```
PS D:\dev\notes> php artisan schema:dump

   PDOException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

  at D:\dev\notes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
     66▕         if (class_exists(PDOConnection::class) && ! $this->isPersistentConnection($options)) {
     67▕             return new PDOConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
     68▕         }
     69▕
     70▕         return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
     71▕     }
     72▕
     73▕     /**
     74▕      * Determine if the connection is persistent.

  1   D:\dev\notes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=notes", "homestead", "secret", [])

  2   D:\dev\notes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:46
      Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector::createPdoConnection("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=notes", "homestead", "secret", [])
```

My .env config:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=notes
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Accessing the database through source code (e.g. inside a controller) works with these settings.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're using Vagrant/Homestead, but trying to run the commands in Windows. Since the database is in Vagrant, you'll need to log into the VM in order to run the commands

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I run the command inside the VM, i get "Could not open input file: artisan". As of my understanding artisan is a helper console provided by laravel, e.g. for creating controller, model source, etc. I think it's not installed inside a Homestead box and I have to call it from my host machine?

Comment: Artisan is part of your project, not an actual command, and lives in the root directory of your project. Make sure you're in your project directory when you call the command.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks!